# Confluent JDBC Kafka Connect multiple tables from different schemas in "table.whitelist"

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to configure Confluents Kafka JDBC connect to stream data from two different tables in two different schemas to 1 topic.  I am having trouble getting my source command to execute when I add multiple tables in table.whitelist

I have two tables from different schemas:  `db1.case` & `db2.case`

When I run the curl command I set the table.whitelist like this

```
"table.whitelist": "case, db1.case, db2.case",
```

but I get an error saying

```
Update the connector's 'table.whitelist' config to include exactly one table in each of the tables listed below.
[["db1"."case", "db2"."case"]]
```

Does anyone know the right way to whitelist multiple tables from multiple schemas?

Comment: Try to use two different connectors

Comment: can you please share your config of jdbc.